# What's the maximum degree of concurrency of the given task dependency graph?

Tags: parallel-processing

Maximum degree of concurrency is the maximum number of task that can be executed concurrenty.

I believe the graph's max degree of concurrency is 2. Because only two task can be executed at the same time and others have to wait for another. However in solution, it was given 8.  What do you think?

[image: Task Dependency Graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for task-dependency graphs that are trees, the 
maximum degree of concurrency is always equal to the number of leaves in the tree. That's why it is 8.